# Created an other account to ask question, but also locked. Why?

Tags: support, rate-limiting, multiple-accounts

It looks that I asked to much question today, then my account has been locked. Then, I created an other account to ask a question (I saw that it was not forbidden), and the other new account is locked since it looks to be connected with this one. How can it be possible ? Is there a way to fix the other account, who would allow me to ask an other question ?

Comment: I'm not sure where you saw that it isn't forbidden, because using a second account to get around a (temporary!!) question ban is most certainly not allowed. See [this question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/21508/is-it-wrong-to-make-a-second-account-if-youve-reached-your-monthly-asking-limit)

Comment: *Creating a new account in order to post more questions than the limit allows is strictly against the rules. The new account will be deleted.* – [Alex Becker (who was a moderator then)](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10436/the-limit-of-asking-a-question?lq=1#comment38630_10436)

Comment: When you tried to ask your question, what did the system say? And what is your new account? (But, yeah, creating accounts to bypass system imposed limitations — in this case I suspect it's the six questions per day limit — is a pretty bad thing to do.)

Comment: Related: [The Limit of asking a question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/10436)

Comment: What did you assume was the purpose of the limit on the number of questions an account can ask?

Comment: @quid: SE likes to tout how many users they have: for example, that there are 4.7M members of the SO community (though [some dispute this figure](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/310847)). When avid question-askers are forced to create new accounts in order to ask more question, there are more accounts created, and therefore more members of the community, and the site is more successful. Then profit, I guess. `/sarcasm`

Comment: @Arthur: So you're making the sarcastic claim that SE is based after the Facebook model? :-)

Comment: ok, sorry about this mistakes, I erased the count :-)

Comment: *sigh* At what point did people start confusing *working within rules* with *working around rules*? Application of this mentality to rules for ethics is pretty appalling.

Comment: @rschwieb I think it happened a few seconds after someone made the first rule.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi True. Pesky rules.

Answer (score 13):

Well, the only particular rule to abide by if you have multiple accounts is:

> Don't use multiple accounts to do anything you couldn't do on a single account.

A particular application of this rule is that you should not avoid any rate limits using two accounts - so, if one account is prevented from asking questions, circumventing this with another account is not permissible.